# Stripe fails to automatically fill the customer email adress to send a receipt

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a stripe checkout up and running (in test mode) and the test cards work well.

Now I don't understand why it does not send the receipt by email on success.

I saw in the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/receipts#automatically-send-receipts-when-payments-are-successful) that we need 1) to allow automatic emailing in the dashboard (it is done) and 2) to specify the email address of the customer in the `checkout.sessions.create` function.

For the moment, stripe does not send the email because I don't specify an email address in `customer_email` field of `checkout.sessions.create`.

What I don't understand is why stripe does not auto-fill the address and send the receipt to it, as stripe checkout is actually collecting an email on the "checkout" page, if that makes sense...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stripe does not send emails in test mode.  The info box on the right side of [Stripe's documentation for email receipts](https://stripe.com/docs/receipts) explains this:

> Receipts for payments created using your test API keys are not sent automatically. Instead, you can view or manually send a receipt using the Dashboard.

Comment: thank you very much I did not see that even if I read the docs several times...